# LiquidFun and cocos creator

Tags: liquidfun, cocoscreator

I am new to cocos creator and JavaScript programming, recently cocos creator added 'Integrated Box2D physics engine' to its engine. And I was wondering if I can use '[liquidFun](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/ReleaseNotes/html/index.html)' within cocos creator. If it is possible, please tell me how can I install this library and use it within my cocos creator.

Comment: Hi. **Cocos Creator** is based on Javascript and **LiquidFun** is a C++ library and as far as I know, there is no conventional way to integrate C++ in a Cocos Creator project. It would be easier to integrate it with Cocos2d-X.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I think it might be possible by [building the JavaScript version of LiquidFun](https://google.github.io/liquidfun/Building/html/md__building_java_script.html) and then importing it in Cocos Creator.